# Apache flink Quick Start "Analyze the Result" error for K-Means

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I followed the implementation of Apache-flink via: [quick_start](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-0.10/quickstart/run_example_quickstart.html)

I am not able to perform the last task i.e. 'Analyze the Result' because there is no result file inside the kmeans folder.

[image]

If you look into the above screenshot of flink JobManager, there you can see Status as FAILED for KMeans Example. And may be due to this failed status there is no result file inside the kmeans folder.

Now on clicking the KMeans Example, I get the following visualization:

[image]
​

And below is the screenshot of exceptions:

[image]
​

Could you please guide me what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the cluster has been started with a single `TaskManager` which has only a single slot and that you want to execute the `KMeans` job at the same time with a parallelism of 4.

In order to run the job with parallelism of 4, you have to increase the number of TaskManager of your cluster or the number of slots on each TaskManager. The latter can be set in the Flink configuration `flink-conf.yaml` with `taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots: 4`. For the former, you can modify the `conf/slaves` file to add new machines for the additional TaskManager.

Alternatively, you can decrease the parallelism of your job to 1. You can control the parallelism with the command line option `-p`. E.g. `bin/flink run -p 1 -c JobClass job.tar`.

Comment: `cd kmeans  
python plotPoints.py result ./result clusters` is given in the quick_start_guide but 'result' is a folder which has files 1,2,3 and 4. My command was:
`cd kmeans  
python plotPoints.py result ./result/1 clusters` which produces output as clusters-plot.pdf

Comment: When you execute your job with a parallelism `> 1`, then the output of each partition is written into a separate file. You would have to fuse the individual files to obtain the complete result and then call `plotPoints.py` on it.